# How to put jq output multi arrays in single array

Tags: jq

While reading data from a json file using jq.
This command `jq ".[]|keys" config.json` gives following output:

```
[
  "N1",
  "N2"
]
[
  "N3",
  "N4"
]
```

What I ideally want is very simple:

```
["N1", "N2", "N3", "N4"]
```

However,
How I cannot find a way to accomplish this.

Config file:

```
{
    "Test1":{
        "N1":{
            "crn":"1",
            "con":"2"
        },
        "N2":{
            "crn":"100",
            "con":"200"
        }
        
    },
    "test2":{
        "N3":{
            "crn":"xx",
            "con":"2x"
        },
        "N4":{
            "crn":"xxxx",
            "con":"3xx"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead:

```sh
jq 'map(keys[])' config.json
```

```json
[
  "N1",
  "N2",
  "N3",
  "N4"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PFhrJziEN0)

Note that `keys` sorts the keys. If you want them unsorted, use `keys_unsorted` instead.

Also, if you want to have the output in one line, add the `--compact-output` (or `-c`) option (thx @Cyrus).

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as answer asap.

Comment: You may want to add the `-c` option.